# Vue set data property inside tiptap editor constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, tiptap

Having trouble setting the value of `editorView` inside of the `onInit` method when creating a new `Editor` instance. Because the call is nested two methods deep, I'm not sure how to access the Vue instance to properly set the `editorView`.

```
data: function() {
    return {
        editor: new Editor({
            onInit: ({ state, view }) => {
                this.editorView = view
            },
        }),
        editorView: null,
    }
},
```

Comment: That should work, actually. The arrow function captures `this`, which should be your component. What does the debugger say if you put a  breakpoint in the callback? Is it possible the `onInit` is run as part of the constructor? In that case Vue had not had a chance to turn the property into a reactive property yet.

Answer (score 1):

I come to discover this library called [tiptap](https://tiptap.scrumpy.io/) and according to its [events](https://tiptap.dev/docs/guide/events.html) you could do that as follows :

```
data: function() {
    return {
        editor: new Editor(),
        editorView: null,
    }
},
mounted(){
 this.editor.on('init', ({ state, view }) => {
   this.editorView = view
})
}
```

Or

```
data: function() {
    return {
        editor: null,
        editorView: null,
    }
},
mounted(){
 let that=this;
 this.editor=new Editor({
            onInit: ({ state, view }) => {
                that.editorView = view
            },
        })
}
```

Since `this` refers to the `Editor` instance not to `Vue` one

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the callback is never fired. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: like i said i come to discover this tool, i gonna to suggest another solution

Comment: `let that=this;` is an ugly practice, use bind()

Comment: but if bind this to the callback how could get access to the editor instance?

Answer (score 1):

Though not ideal, a temporary fix is to pull the initialization inside of `mounted` and store the Vue instance to a temp var. If anyone has a way to access the Vue instance from the init callback inside the original constructor I would appreciate it. Thanks!

```
    mounted: function() {
        this.initializeEditor() 
    },
    methods: {
        initializeEditor() {
            var self = this
            this.editor = new Editor({
                onInit: ({ state, view }) => {
                    console.log('Editor Initialized.')
                    console.log('Editor view: ')
                    self.editorView = view
                },
            })
        },
    }
```

Comment: This is the best way because you cannot update a data property by another one since they're initialized in the same time, `this` in the callback refers to editor instance not to vue one, i added this in my answer below